# Parse Server migration without tool

Tags: heroku, migration, parse-server, mlab

I'm working to revive an app that was originally hosted on Parse. I have access to a Bitbucket with the app code but the database itself was not migrated before Parse.com shut down. I would like to run the app through Parse Server (using mlab and heroku) but all documentation I've found online requires use of the Parse migration tool (Which is no longer available).

I understand that I can use the Parse Server example project on github and paste in my own app code to set up my app. Do I do paste in my code before or after deploying to Heroku/mlab? Also, which files should I keep from the parse-server-example and which should I delete? Are there other steps I should be aware of that become necessary without access to the Parse migration tool?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't migrate your database off of the Parse.com hosted service after January 30th, 2017.

Since you don't have a database to migrate, you can start a new Parse Server project from scratch. You can just follow the Getting Started With Heroku + mLab Development steps on the [parse-server-example](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example) project, and add any existing cloud functions to the /cloud directory once you've cloned the project.

Comment: Great, thanks! So I'll add my cloud code into the example project. Should I also delete any of the example code or is it okay to leave it all in there?

Comment: Once you have it running, it looks like visiting the base URL will display a message, and visiting /test will display a test page that they suggest removing. You can begin adding in routes or additional pages within the index.js file, but what your application actually renders is totally up to you.